# Why are my serialized files 0 bytes? And why is it throwing an EOF error when reading them?

Tags: java, serialization, eof

I'm working on a game project and I'm creating a save feature. I'm using serialized files in order to directly save objects and retrieve them later. I only have to save one `ArrayList<Direction>`, where `Direction` is a custom enum containing `UP`, `DOWN`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `NULL` and `RESTART` for special contexts.

In my code, I create an `ArrayList<Direction>` containing every movement the user has done since the beginning of the game, and make a save button that stores that ArrayList in a file. Writing the object in the file seems to be fine, no error is thrown or whatever. When using the load button that retrieves the object from the file, I'm getting an EOF error (error is written below the code).

I have noticed my files are 0 bytes, which makes me wonder if the data is actually written in the file, and that could explain the EOF error. I have tried changing the file extension, flushing the `ObjectOutputStream` before closing it, changing the file name, but none of these seem to fix the issue. Clearly, I need to understand why my file is 0 bytes (and thus preventing me from retrieving any data) and why I'm getting an EOF error when reading the file.

Here is the used code:

```java
public class LevelSaver {
    public LevelSaver() {
    }

    public void saveLevel(ArrayList<Direction> movesHistory, byte level) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "level" + (level < 10 ? "0" + level : level);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy @ HH-mm-ss");
        String currentTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
        fileName += " " + currentTime;
        fileName += ".moves";

        File saveFile = new File("src\\main\\resources\\level\\saves\\" + fileName);

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;

        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("src\\main\\resources\\level\\saves" + fileName);
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(movesHistory);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        saveFile.createNewFile();
    }

    public ArrayList<Direction> getHistory(String fileName) {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\level\\saves\\" + fileName);
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            return (ArrayList<Direction>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (objectInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    objectInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

`saveLevel()` creates a `.mov` file containing the `ArrayList`, and `getHistory()` returns an `ArrayList` stored in a file. At least they're supposed to.

Here is what happens when using the F and G keys that respectively save and load the moves history.

```java
case F:
    try {
        levelSaver.saveLevel(movesHistory, currentLevel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    direction = Direction.NULL;
    break;
case G:
    // I'm directly specifying the file and it is intended, the file name is correct
    ArrayList<Direction> res = levelSaver.getHistory("level06 09-04-2021 @ 22-08-57.mov");
    direction = Direction.NULL;
    for (Direction dir : res) {
        System.out.print("applied : " + dir);
        // apply moves applies the given move and changes the displayed map on the screen
        applyMove(dir);
    }
    break;
```

And here is the error that I get when I use the loading function. The error occurs when creating the ObjectInputStream.

```
java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2932)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3427)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:962)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:405)
        at model.LevelSaver.getHistory(LevelSaver.java:41)
        at view.PlayingMenu$1.handle(PlayingMenu.java:150)
        at view.PlayingMenu$1.handle(PlayingMenu.java:87)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4064)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2123)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2591)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: The `EOFException` is because it is 0 length, and it is 0 length because you called `saveFile.createNewFile()` after you had written to the file. Just remove that. NB Dion't repeat string literals. This is just an invitation to typos.

Comment: @user207421 It sounds plausible at first look, but [`File.createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) should only create a file if non exist yet: _"Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't close either stream.

Use try-with-resources:

```
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("src\\main\\resources\\level\\saves" + fileName);
         ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(movesHistory);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: True but this is not why the file is 0 length, and you haven't answered the question about `EOFException`.

Comment: @user207421: Yes, it is.  Without closing the file, no content ever actually gets written to the file, and if it's of size zero, of course it'll EOFException immediately.

Comment: No. Every `writeObject()` writes and flushes data, and the header is also auto-flushed, there being no `BufferedOutputStream` here; and the `EOFException` is because constructing the `ObjectInputStream` tries to read the header. Opening a zero-length file with most other streams doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: Closing the streams with a try-with-resources is not necessary, and this worked for me. Thanks for the answer, marking it as final answer.

Comment: @Nephty If it isn't necessary how could it have possibly worked for you? The issue was the `createNewFile()` call. There is nothing about this answer that you should mark it as correct. It isn't.